# how to translate curl to elixir httpoison

Tags: rest, curl, elixir, httpoison

I have an example curl command from an api:

```
curl -sd '{"inputs":[{"addresses": ["add42af7dd58b27e1e6ca5c4fdc01214b52d382f"]}],"outputs":[{"addresses": ["884bae20ee442a1d53a1d44b1067af42f896e541"], "value": 4200000000000000}]}' https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/txs/new?token=YOURTOKEN
```

I have no idea how to translate this into HTTPoison for Elixir. I've been trying for hours. I can't even begin to mention all the iterations I've gone through, but here's where I'm at now:

```
Connect.post( "https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/txs/new?token=#{@token}",
              "",
              [
                { "inputs",  "{addresses, #{address_from}}"},
                {  "outputs", "[{addresses, #{address_to}}, {value, #{eth_amount}}]"}
              ]
            )
```

unlike most everything I've tried before this actually gets to their servers and gives a response:

```
"{\"error\": \"Couldn't deserialize request: EOF\"}"
%{"error" => "Couldn't deserialize request: EOF"}
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Base.encode16/2
         (elixir) lib/base.ex:175: Base.encode16(nil, [])
    (blockcypher) lib/blockcypher/handler.ex:55: Blockcypher.Handler.post_transa
ction_new/4
iex(46)>
```

can you help me out? I tried putting the data in the body portion instead of the headers but with no luck.

Comment: https://curlconverter.com/elixir (disclaimer: I maintain this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data should be the second argument to `HTTPoison.post/2` and should be encoded to JSON. Your data is also in the wrong format.

This should work:

```
Connect.post(
  "https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/eth/main/txs/new?token=#{@token}",
  "",
  Poison.encode!(
    %{"inputs" => [%{"addresses" => [address_from]}],
      "outputs" => [%{"addresses" => [address_to],
                      "value" => eth_amount}]})
)
```

Comment: thanks Dogbert, unfortunately that didn't work. I got an error saying `** (Poison.SyntaxError) Unexpected end of input at position 0
         (poison) lib/poison/parser.ex:55: Poison.Parser.parse!/2
         (poison) lib/poison.ex:83: Poison.decode!/2
      (httpoison) lib/httpoison/base.ex:471: HTTPoison.Base.response/6
    (blockcypher) lib/blockcypher/handler.ex:47: Blockcypher.Handler.post_transa
ction_new/4`

Comment: @Dogbert in the original request, both `inputs` and `outputs[addresses+value]` are _arrays_. I believe wrapping maps into `[]` should make it working.

Comment: @mudasobwa thanks! I've decoded the original string with `Poison.decode!` and copy-pasted it. Hopefully there are no errors now! @LegitStack could you try my new code?

Comment: that worked! with the slight modification of removing the 3rd line `"",` Thanks guys, you're wizards!